# somar coluna expressão lambda

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

preciso retornar a soma da coluna valor_negocio, tenho a seguinte expressão

```
dynamic contato = (from a in context.Negocio
                   join cli in context.Pessoa on a.id_cliente equals cli.id_pessoa
                   join col in context.Pessoa on a.id_colaborador equals col.id_pessoa
                   where cli.id_empresa == idEmpresa                                               
                   && a.data_inicio >= dataInicial
                   && a.data_inicio <= dataFinal
                   && a.status == "Contato"
                   && (idCliente == 0 ? a.id_cliente != 0 : a.id_cliente == idCliente)
                   && (idColaborador == 0 ? a.id_colaborador != 0 : a.id_colaborador == idColaborador)
                   select new
                   {
                       a.id_negocio,
                       a.id_colaborador,
                       a.id_cliente,
                       a.id_empresa,
                       cli = cli.razao,
                       col = col.razao,
                       a.titulo,
                       a.descricao,
                       a.valor_mensalidade,
                       a.valor_negocio,
                       a.cli_primens,
                       //a.data_inicio,
                       //a.data_fim,
                       a.status                                                   
                   }).ToList();
```

como alterar para trazer também o somatório da coluna valor_negocio?
exemplo: se no banco tiver 10 registros, e cada registro o valor_negocio é 10, preciso que seja retornado 100

Comment: Se precisa agrupar os valores ????

Comment: Virgilio, preciso somar os valores, se no banco tiver 10 registros, e cada registro o valor_negocio é 10, preciso que seja retornado 100

Comment: Precisar agrupar então isso vai retornar dependendo do agrupamento 1 linha para cada ! é isso que precisa?

Comment: quero apenas uma linha com o total (do campo valor_negocio ) de todos os registros

Answer (score 1):

Se o que precisa é apenas a soma de `valor_negocio`, então pode descartar o operador `select`, pois ele é usado apenas se quiser retornar dados de cada registro:

```
var somaValorNegocio =
               (from a in context.Negocio
               join cli in context.Pessoa on a.id_cliente equals cli.id_pessoa
               join col in context.Pessoa on a.id_colaborador equals col.id_pessoa
               where cli.id_empresa == idEmpresa                                               
               && a.data_inicio >= dataInicial
               && a.data_inicio <= dataFinal
               && a.status == "Contato"
               && (idCliente == 0 ? a.id_cliente != 0 : a.id_cliente == idCliente)
               && (idColaborador == 0 ? a.id_colaborador != 0 : a.id_colaborador == idColaborador)
               select a.valor_negocio)
               .Sum();
```

Agora dependendo do tipo de `valor_negocio`, voce terá o total somado na variável local `somaValorNegocio`.

Imagino que era isto que estava procurando.

Comment: Pediu pra colocar um select ou um group

Comment: @alessandremartins, realmente ao usar essa sintaxe de Linq, é necessário o uso de select ou group. Para não re-escrever toda query, só colocar a select e retirar o argumento do Sum. Corrigi no código, vê se fucniona.